# How to grab a large array of cells quickly and preserve leading zeros - Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Grabbing a large range of cells and moving them into an array isn't very difficult with the `Variant` data type:

```
Dim primaryArray As Variant
primaryArray = Range("A2:A276000").Value2
```

However, I require the array to contain strings that may or may not have leading zeros and I can't figure out how to control what kind of variable the variant array saves as.

Of course I could convert the array to a string array afterwards:

```
Dim sPrimaryArray() As String
ReDim sPrimaryArray(LBound(primaryArray) To UBound(primaryArray)) As String
For i = LBound(primaryArray) To UBound(primaryArray)
    sPrimaryArray(i) = CStr(primaryArray(i, 1))
Next
```

Unfortunately, in my case, leading zeros must be preserved. When the variant array automatically saves as a `Double` (as it does in this case) it deletes the leading zeros, so converting to a string after this is pointless because I've lost the leading zeros that I needed to match the string reliably.

Furthermore, this requires looping which is something I rather try to avoid. With over 200,000 entries, looping can take a long time.

Is there any possible way to:

- A. Force a variant array to use the string data type
- B. Convert a range of cells directly to a string array without looping

Comment: If you actually have Strings with leading zeroes, that should load into the array just fine. If you have numbers formatted to display leading zeroes, you'll need to loop, unless there is a consistent format to the data.

Comment: There is a consistent format. They are all 10 digit numbers that may or may not have leading zeros. However, it's really strange, changing the format of the column to text does nothing but if you edit one of the values, even if you don't change anything, it gets that green triangle in the corner that means `Number Stored as Text` and after that point it automatically saves as a string in the array. But I need a way to programmatically force them to always be strings.

Comment: Because the value in the Excel cell is a number, it will be saved as a number value in the array. When the number is stored as a text in Excel, this will store as a string in the array.

As far as Excel is concerned, "000050" and 000050 are two different values.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. That's the purpose of my question, I need to know how to make it not do that.

Comment: I believe `B` is not possible. Thus `A` shouldn't be an issue as you anyway have to loop to convert to String array(just make a 10 length string everytime)

Comment: Even if you don't mind formatting the worksheet via `Range("A1:A10").NumberFormat="@"`, you will have to use loops to reformat the cell.

VBA is okay but there's a lot missing from it compared to modern languages.

Comment: If you use `.Text` instead of `.Value2` it will preserve the leading 0's. (but it's slower)

Comment: @brax +1 it should be better than handling the messy details with String handling in VBA.

Comment: It doesn't work if you change it to `.Text` it always gets a Type Mismatch Error

Comment: For multiple cells, `.Text` returns `Null` if they don't all have exactly the same *displayed* value, and a single value, rather than an array, if they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are all the same format, you can use a simple `Evaluate` call:

```
Dim primaryArray As Variant
primaryArray As Variant = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("INDEX(TEXT(A2:A276000,""0000000000""),)")
```

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but this looks like the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Now I've tested it and yes, this is the simplest answer as long as there's a consistent format.